# How can I determine if all business rules are met in an entity form in Dynamics CRM 2013?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a form with two fields

```
e-mail
telephone
```

and a business rule that validates that at least one of them is set. There is a Silverlight application in the CRM that needs to know if the form can be saved or not. This should be done without saving it, thus invoking save() and catching exceptions is not an option. I can invoke Javascript from the Silverlight application, so a JS solution would be fine, too.

How can the SL application (or a JS function) know whether or not the form can be saved?

Happy coding

Arne

Comment: You are likely going to need to duplicate the validation in JavaScript to make sure at least one of them has been set. Is that not an option?
I would probably just move the logic out of the business rule and put it into a function that is called onsave. This way you could call it from your Silverlight app as well.

Comment: currently it is done with javascript but that is considered not flexible enough. The Customer should be able to change the fields and the logic behind them and for that he uses business rules. Thus the goal is to do the complete validation in JS and let the SL app use this validation mechanism to decide if the form gets saved or not.

Comment: Correction: The goal is to the complete validation with business rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say your business rule "validates" that one or the other is filled in. What action does it take if this is the case? I can think of several approaches to this, such as testing if one is NULL, make the other required.

You could just test to see if both are null, and show an error message against one or both. Displaying an error message from a rule will block saving of the record. Whether this will be enough to block your SL app from trying to save it as well, I'm not sure.

Comment: Currently I show an error message on both fields and make both fields mandatory. When I check the mandatory state with javascript like this: if (attribute.getRequiredLevel() == 'required')  then I see them as not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. In case this helps someone, I created business rules that make fields mandatory when some conditions are met. Then I created a JS function that checks if all fields that are mandatory are actually filled. This function did not work correctly for me. Here is the working version:

```
function IsAllMandatoryFieldsPopulated() {
    var populated = true;

    Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.forEach(function (attribute, index) {
        if (attribute.getRequiredLevel() == 'required') {
            if(attribute.getValue() === null) {
                populated = false;
            }
        }
    });

    if (populated)
        return '';
    return 'Put your validation message here';
}
```

It did not work because of some hassles you get when you call this function form SL, but that is out of scope for this question. Hope this helps someone.